# MySql (select function()=1) vs (function()=1) inside query. Which one is faster?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a function in MySql named MyFunction(param). It gives result as 0 or 1 based on some condition written inside calculated by a parameter passed. I wish to use it in my views and select records based on that condition. Which of the following will work faster if I have about million records in table -

```
select * from sometable where (MyFunction(sometable.somecolumn)=1)

select * from sometable where (select MyFunction(sometable.somecolumn)=1)
```

Both work just fine but not sure which one is more optimized one.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have two queries and ask *us* which one runs faster? What's stopping you from finding out yourself? You have the data and the server and the SQL right there!

Comment: I don't have millions of data right now. But in future table will have that much of data. I thought asking experts and finding which one is faster and WHY is it faster would be better than finding it myself.

Comment: I saw several examples with similar syntax. And there is no difference (in MySQL). Word 'select' is not necessary in this case.

Comment: Okay thanks. Will remove select then

Comment: It's not difficult to create millions of rows if you want to test things.

Comment: I would create millions of rows @Tomalak but even If I get to the result which one was faster I don't know "WHY" it was

Comment: But that would be a totally different question than the one you've asked, and a much better one.

Comment: Ya, the point was which one is faster and why but anyways, none of them is faster. Both run at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of them will run faster if the table has millions of records. The reason is it can't apply an index on a column once you applied a function on it. Ideally both of following queries should gives you the same result and both should have table scan regardless of having an index on "sometable.somecolumn"

```
explain select * from sometable where (MyFunction(sometable.somecolumn)=1)

explain select * from sometable where (select MyFunction(sometable.somecolumn)=1)
```

Comment: Yes, both will act in same way

Comment: Please note, none of them will run faster.

Comment: Yes ok.. Will use the one without select as select keyword is optional